# Creating an accordion style menu

Tags: menus, navigation

Is there any way to create a menu with dropdown list like the image below in WordPress ?

[image: accordion menu]
<sup>*click to enlarge* ⤴</sup>

Here, when we click on [+] sign the dropdown menu shows up, I can manage the CSS, but what would be the code to make this possible?

Comment: This is a JS/css question not a WordPress question. There's nothing special on the WordPress side you need to do beyond print out a menu, which is done in every theme out there

Comment: I don't want Js/Css part, possible to output the dropdown links inside a "div" and outside the <li> tag ? I wan't the code if it can output the html in a defined manner ...

Comment: Nav menus already do that, go look up the codex entry ( like you should have done in your research prior to asking ) and you'll see you can change that html too. You can also insert it via JS ( what happens if you insert via PHP and the js breaks or end user has js turned off? )

Comment: NO i am not geting the way to bring the dropdown portion out of the <li> tag, that's why i am asking if their is any way, as i have written, css/js is not a issue, but i am new to wordpress and i have fully read the codex part of WP_NAV_MENUS but did't find any answer.

Comment: I don't see why you can't do something like: `<div id="accordion">title<span>arrow</span><?php wp_nav_menu(...); ?> </div>`. Besides you clearly didn't view the codex or you would have spotted the `items_wrap` argument

Answer (score 0):

The code for WordPress would be:

1. [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) for custom nav menus
2. [`wp_page_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu) as the default fallback for custom nav menus
3. [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) for a list of static pages

See the linked Codex pages for the various parameters to pass to each, and the CSS classes output by each.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, the functions i know but how should i do that, is do you know any Key=>value pair for the same ?

Comment: Css class output is not possible as Jquery required for onclick function, i suppose (sorry for bad english)

Comment: The functions above will provide the HTML markup for the menu. If your question regards how to manipulate that markup with a particular jQuery script or library, such a question isn't *WordPress*-related.

Comment: In that case is it possible to output the dropdown links inside a "div" and outside the <li> tag ?

Comment: Did you read the linked Codex entries?